# MailItem.Display(true|false) exception when used in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, email, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm creating an Outlook Add In, which has a subform. The form has a button on it, through which I would like to generate a mailitem, if the user clicks it. I'd like to auto-populate some info in the email, and then leave it for the user to send at their leisure.

My code looks like the following:

```
private void btnMailDocNotice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string clientInfo = string.Empty;
        string matInfo = string.Empty;
        string author = string.Empty;
        string dType = string.Empty;
        string fLocation = string.Empty;
        string keyWords = string.Empty;
        string docName = string.Empty;

        clientInfo = this.mCboClient.Text + " " + lblClient;
        matInfo = this.mCboMatter.Text + " " + lblMatter;
        author = this.txtAuthor.Text;
        dType = this.mCboDocType.Text.ToUpper();
        fLocation = this.txtSavePath.Text;
        keyWords = this.txtKeyWords.Text;
        docName = this.txtDocName.Text;

        this.sendDocNotice = true;
        this.Hide();
        CreateMailItem(clientInfo, matInfo, author, dType, this.operatorCode.ToUpper(), fLocation, keyWords, docName);
        this.Show();
    }

private void CreateMailItem(string clientInfo, string matInfo, string author, string dType, string profiledBy, string fLocation, string keyWords, string docName)
    {
        this.DNoticeItem = (Outlook.MailItem)ThisAddIn.myApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        this.DNoticeItem.Subject = "Document: " + docName;
        this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody = "<span style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size: 11pt;\">KeyWords: " + keyWords + "</span>";
        this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody += "<br />Client: " + clientInfo;
        this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody += "<br />Matter: " + matInfo;
        this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody += "<br />Author: " + author;
        this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody += "<br />Doc Type: " + dtClient;
        this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody += "<br />Profiled by: " + profiledBy;
        this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody += "<br />File://" + fLocation;
        this.DNoticeItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
        this.DNoticeItem.Display(false);
    }
```

The problem that I'm running into, is it fires an exception on the mailitem.display function, whether I use true or false (doing a bit of research says that determines if the user can access the main Outlook window or not while the mailitem is open). The exception is a COM Exception of "A dialog box is open. Close it and try again". I've tried hiding the WinForm prior to the function call that creates the mail item, then show it again after the function is exited, but it didn't work. I've tried a version of the code where I use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() to try and open the file after saving it to disk, and while it doesn't fire an exception from the add in, Outlook prompts the user with a message box of the same message from the ComException. I even tried creating a field to see if the doc notice email should be drafted, and thought to have the code take care of that after a form.close() call, thinking the close call would at least dispose of the dialog box that was locking Outlook, and I still got the same exception.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm kind of stuck at the moment, and would appreciate any help/pointers/suggestions anyone has to offer in this issue. My sincere apologies if this is a duplicative question - I couldn't find a good answer to the question. Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, why not display yoru own form modelessly?

Secondly (and this is pretty important) do **not** use code like the following

```
this.DNoticeItem.HTMLBody += "<br />Client: " + clientInfo;
```

Every time you run a line like that, you retrieve HTMLBody, add some stuff to it (making the HTML malformed), then set HTMLBody again and force Outlook to make sense of your (malformed) HTML. This (assuming Outlook can parse and fix your HTML) will result in HTML being returned to be different from what you set it to.

Build the HTML body once using a regular string, and set HTMLBody property only once.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance - can you give me an example of displaying a form modelessly? I'm unfamiliar with the term. Thanks for the tip on the HTML, had no idea re: HTMLBody. I'll construct, then apply once as you recommend.

Comment: Prompt prompt = new Prompt(mail, OutlookItemType.Sent);
prompt.ShowDialog();

Comment: Replace ShowDialog with Show().

Comment: I just tried that and still get the exception. Also, weirdly, the tab button no longer switches from control to control. Pressing tab while in any field save a multi line textbox results in a windows beep. Switching back to ShowDialog at least restores tab functionality...

Comment: Is your form created as the child of the appropriate Outlook window?

Comment: Sorry I'm unclear what you mean. My add in hooks into the sent items folder, items_add event. The form is an item added to the solution via add new item->windows form in visual studio. I don't recall having to set a parent window property. Is that the incorrect way of doing that? This is my first add in and so admittedly may have screwed this up. I appreciate your patience in my beginner questions

Comment: Windows API wise, your form must be a child of Outlook. You can cast Application.ActiveWindow as IOleWindow, call IOleWindow.GetWindow to retrieve the parent HWND, then use NativeWindow class (see MSDN) to show your dialog using Fomr.Show(NativeWindow ).

Comment: Thank you so much. Turns out just changing it to Show() was enough to get the behavior I wanted as you originally stated. The reason it didn't work for me the first time, and that the Tab key stopped shifting from control to control was because of another add in - somehow I could mouse out, etc, but it had wrested control of the tab key? Once I removed that add in, all was fine. Again, thank you so much for your help!